# How to add python3 support to MacVim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, macvim, ultisnips

I recently installed MacVim (not through brew), and as I was trying to set up some basic configurations, I encountered an issue with python3 and the UltiSnips plugin. My vimrc is currently just a very basic one that I downloaded from vim bootstrap, and every time I try to edit something in insert mode, I get the following error: 
`` Error detected while processing /Users/name/.vim/plugged/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips.vim`: line    7: E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: py3 import vim `` 
The `:version` command is telling me that I am not on the "small version" of macvim, but it is saying that I don't have the python3 feature. How can I add this feature?

The output of `:version` after redownloading MacVim is

```
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +clientserver      +diff              +folding           +lambda            +mouseshape        +netbeans_intg     +python3/dyn       +statusline        +textprop          +vreplace
+arabic            +clipboard         +digraphs          -footer            +langmap           +mouse_dec         +num64             +quickfix          -sun_workshop      +timers            +wildignore
+autocmd           +cmdline_compl     +dnd               +fork()            +libcall           -mouse_gpm         +odbeditor         +reltime           +syntax            +title             +wildmenu
+autochdir         +cmdline_hist      -ebcdic            +fullscreen        +linebreak         -mouse_jsbterm     +packages          +rightleft         +tag_binary        +toolbar           +windows
-autoservername    +cmdline_info      +emacs_tags        +gettext           +lispindent        +mouse_netterm     +path_extra        +ruby/dyn          -tag_old_static    +transparency      +writebackup
+balloon_eval      +comments          +eval              -hangul_input      +listcmds          +mouse_sgr         +perl/dyn          +scrollbind        -tag_any_white     +user_commands     -X11
+balloon_eval_term +conceal           +ex_extra          +iconv             +localmap          -mouse_sysmouse    +persistent_undo   +signs             -tcl               +vartabs           -xfontset
+browse            +cryptv            +extra_search      +insert_expand     +lua/dyn           +mouse_urxvt       +popupwin          +smartindent       +termguicolors     +vertsplit         +xim
++builtin_terms    +cscope            -farsi             +ipv6              +menu              +mouse_xterm       +postscript        -sodium            +terminal          +virtualedit       -xpm
+byte_offset       +cursorbind        +file_in_path      +job               +mksession         +multi_byte        +printer           -sound             +terminfo          +visual            -xsmp
+channel           +cursorshape       +find_in_path      +jumplist          +modify_fname      +multi_lang        +profile           +spell             +termresponse      +visualextra       -xterm_clipboard
+cindent           +dialog_con_gui    +float             +keymap            +mouse             -mzscheme          +python/dyn        +startuptime       +textobjects       +viminfo           -xterm_save
```

Comment: Please add the *full* output of `:version`, ideally as text.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you got that "MacVim" from, but `:version` is supposed to report the following in the latest build (9.0.65 (173)):

```
[...]
+python/dyn
+python3/dyn
[...]
```

so it looks like you are not using MacVim to begin with. FWIW, you should have the following as well:

```
+profile
+rightleft
```

which you don't.

Once you get [a proper MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases/tag/snapshot-173), see `:help 'pythonthreehome'` and `:help 'pythonthreedll'`.

Comment: Thanks, reinstalling MacVim worked to solve my initial issue. I don't know why I didn't have python3 installed the first time. But, I am still getting the following error: ```Error detected while processing TextChangedI Autocommands for "*"..function UltiSnips#TrackChange:
line    1:
E837: This Vim cannot execute :py3 after using :python```. How can I check which plugin is causing the issue?

Comment: Find out what plugin of yours requires Python.

Comment: How do I do that? I can't comment any lines of code out because the error prevents me from typing.

Comment: Well, *you* installed them so *you* know their dependencies, right? If you don't, which is a problem in and of itself, check their `README`s, or `grep` your `.vim` for `:py`, or proceed via bisection.